# NSOperation with more than one long task

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

In my understanding, the long running task of an `NSOperation` should be implemented in its `main` function, where it gets triggered once the `NSOperation` is added to an `NSOperationQueue`.

This worked fine for me, until now, where my `NSOperation` has more than one major task.

First task is to parse a document (should be applied only once when opening the doc).

Second task is to append `NSData` to the document (can be called several times for an opened doc).

The only solution I can think of is moving both tasks into the `main` function, and deciding at runtime which task to execute:

```
- (void)main
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        if(firstTaskTsDone)
        {
            [self doSecondTask];
        }
        else
        {    
            [self doFirstTask];
            firstTaskTsDone = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

But I guess there must be a better way to achieve this?

ALSO: How can I achieve the same result using a concurrent operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a second `NSOperation` for the second task.  You can use:

```
[secondOperation addDependency:firstOperation];
```

To make the second operation starting dependant on the first operation finishing.  You can then add both these operations to the `NSOperationQueue`.  In the second operation you can use its `dependencies` property to access the first operation and extract any data that the second operation may need to complete it's task.

Another approach could be to configure the `NSOperationQueue` to be a serial queue:

```
[operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

In which case you wouldn't need to set dependancies and the order in which you add the first and second `NSOperation` would determine the order they run in.

**How can I achieve the same result using a concurrent operation?**

`NSOperationQueue` and `NSOperations` primary purpose is to make non-concurrent tasks concurrent.  If your code doesn't already involve some kind of concurrent task then there is no reason to use a concurrent `NSOperation`.

A common example of a concurrent task is an `NSURLConnection` request.  This is commonly wrapped in a concurrent `NSOperation` so it can be added to an `NSOperationQueue` as part of a longer process where other `NSOperations` would be added to the queue to process the results of the request.

A normal `NSOperation` is finished when the `main` method returns.  If you started an `NSURLConnection` asynchronously in `main` you would return immediately before the connection had finished.  By configuring it as a concurrent operation you take responsibility for signalling to the `NSOperationQueue` when the connection has actually finished.